# Lambda receive Post File and Send to AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I'm creating a microservice in Lambda and I'm trying to make this:

Lambda Api to receive a POST with a CSV File and send this file to AWS S3

I'm creating with NodeJS.

But what I see, is that I must define an Body Mapping that receive FILE and then process in Lambda NodeJS

Can someone help me with the steps?